# Finding tuples in a list

Tags: python

I'm confused on how to find tuples within a list and remove the tuples as well as the value inside of it in python for example,

```
mylist = [12, 'Mark', 34.23(45)]

Output = [12, 'Mark', 34.23]
```

If the list had multiple tuples everywhere, how would I go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: First line of code is invalid (syntactically incorrect).

Comment: @MichaelButscher as a nitpick, the first line throws a `TypeError` rather than a `SyntaxError` since `34.23` is viewed as a callable.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Right, thanks.

Comment: tuple in a list is supposed to be like [12, 'Mark', (34.23,45)], not what you typed. is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Using functional approach if you have tuples in a list, you canapply a filter with a function which returns true for all except tuples.

```
my_list = [12, 'Mark', (34.23,45)]
filter_obj= filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x,tuple), my_list)
#above line is equvalent to (x for x in my_list if not isinstance(x, tuple)) which returns a generator 
processed_list = list(filter_obj)
```

Or you can generate a list directly usng list comprehension.

```
my_list = [12, 'Mark', (34.23,45)]
processed_lsit = [x for x in my_list if not isinstance(x,tuple)]
```

Comment: Just another alternative `[i for i in my_list if not isinstance(i,tuple)]`

Comment: yeah, that'd be simple enough.

Comment: The second approach is using **list comprehension** . And I would recommend to use `isinstance` instead of `type`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the type of list elements, and if it is of type tuple, simply remove it. Considering your list to be

```
mylist = [12, 'Mark', (34.23, 45)]
for i in mylist:
    if type(i) == tuple:
        mylist.remove(i)
```

After this code executes, `mylist` is updated to

```
[12, 'Mark']
```

Answer (score -1):

As Michael said the code is incorrect. But in case you have tuples in a list, for example [12, 'Mark', (34.23,45),21]. This could be removed checking for the "type" of the elements present in the list.

```
mylist = [12, 'Mark', (34.23,45),21]

for elements in mylist:
    if str(type(elements)) in "<class 'tuple'>":
        mylist.remove(elements)

print(mylist)
```

Comment: Instead of using `type` use `isinstance(obj,class)`.

Comment: And mutating list while iterating is never recommended and shouldn't be.